# Remove the elements of array which are present in second array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays :

1. `Array Dates`

> ```
>    Array
>     (
>         [0] => 2015-07-02
>         [1] => 2015-07-03
>         [2] => 2015-07-04
>         [3] => 2015-07-05
>         [4] => 2015-07-06
>         [5] => 2015-07-07
>         [6] => 2015-07-08
>         [7] => 2015-07-09
>         [8] => 2015-07-10
>         [9] => 2015-07-11
>         [10] => 2015-07-12
>         [11] => 2015-07-13
>         [12] => 2015-07-14
>         [13] => 2015-07-15
>         [14] => 2015-07-16
>         [15] => 2015-07-17
>         [16] => 2015-07-18
>         [17] => 2015-07-19
>         [18] => 2015-07-20
>         [19] => 2015-07-21
>         [20] => 2015-07-22
>         [21] => 2015-07-23
>         [22] => 2015-07-24
>         [23] => 2015-07-25
>         [24] => 2015-07-26
>         [25] => 2015-07-27
>         [26] => 2015-07-28
>         [27] => 2015-07-29
>         [28] => 2015-07-30
>         [29] => 2015-07-31
>         [30] => 2015-08-01
>     )
> ```

2- `Array Finald`

>

```
 Array (
>     [0] => 2015-07-07
>     [1] => 2015-07-14
>     [2] => 2015-07-21
>     [3] => 2015-07-28
>     [4] => 2015-08-04
>     [5] => 2015-08-11
>     [6] => 2015-08-18
>     [7] => 2015-08-25
>     [8] => 2015-09-01
>     [9] => 2015-09-08
>     [10] => 2015-09-15
>     [11] => 2015-09-22
>     [12] => 2015-09-29
>     [13] => 2015-10-06
>     [14] => 2015-10-13
>     [15] => 2015-10-20
>     [16] => 2015-10-27
>     [17] => 2015-11-03
>     [18] => 2015-11-10
>     [19] => 2015-11-17
>     [20] => 2015-11-24
>     [21] => 2015-07-16
>     [22] => 2015-07-23
>     [23] => 2015-07-30
>     [24] => 2015-08-06
>     [25] => 2015-08-13
>     [26] => 2015-08-20
>     [27] => 2015-08-27
>     [28] => 2015-09-03
>     [29] => 2015-09-10
>     [30] => 2015-09-17
>     [31] => 2015-09-24
>     [32] => 2015-10-01
>     [33] => 2015-10-08
>     [34] => 2015-10-15
>     [35] => 2015-10-22
>     [36] => 2015-10-29
>     [37] => 2015-11-05
>     [38] => 2015-11-12
>     [39] => 2015-11-19
>     [40] => 2015-11-26
>     [41] => 2015-12-03 )
```

I want to remove elements from array `dates` which are not present in `finald` array. I am using the following code :

```
$tags = array_diff($dates, $finald);
```

I am getting the following array

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => 2015-07-02
>     [1] => 2015-07-03
>     [2] => 2015-07-04
>     [3] => 2015-07-05
>     [4] => 2015-07-06
>     [6] => 2015-07-08
>     [7] => 2015-07-09
>     [8] => 2015-07-10
>     [9] => 2015-07-11
>     [10] => 2015-07-12
>     [11] => 2015-07-13
>     [13] => 2015-07-15
>     [15] => 2015-07-17
>     [16] => 2015-07-18
>     [17] => 2015-07-19
>     [18] => 2015-07-20
>     [20] => 2015-07-22
>     [22] => 2015-07-24
>     [23] => 2015-07-25
>     [24] => 2015-07-26
>     [25] => 2015-07-27
>     [27] => 2015-07-29
>     [29] => 2015-07-31
>     [30] => 2015-08-01
>     [5] => 2015-07-06
>     [12] => 2015-07-13
>     [14] => 2015-07-15
>     [19] => 2015-07-20
>     [21] => 2015-07-22
> )
> ```

I am not getting Why `16-07-2015` and `23-07-2015` is removed from the final `tags` array

Comment: They exist in your second array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*remove elements from array dates which are not present in finald*

So, save that are in both arrays?

```
$dates = Array
    (
        '2015-07-02',        
        '2015-07-03');
$finald =  array(
        '2015-07-02',        
        '2015-07-07');
print_r(array_intersect($dates, $finald));
```

result

```
Array ( [0] => 2015-07-02 )
```

Answer (score 2):

Dates `16-07-2015` and `23-07-2015` exists in second array